# div being positioned improperly

Tags: css

I'm using the exact same method on this page as I am on the rest (which work fine).  So I'm not exactly sure what is wrong. I have tried a few different things, and none have seemed to work.

Apparently I can't post images because I'm fairly new to this wonderful website. There for I put them up to view.

This first image is how it SHOULD look.

www.beerbattle.net/correct.png

This second image is how it currently looks.

www.beerbattle.net/incorrect.png

HTML in question:

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div>
<form id=submit_msg>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Processed</legend>
      <ol id=whatever>
         <li id=whatever>
Thank you for your Submission of [Anheuser-Busch, Inc. Budweiser American Ale]
     </li>
      </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
form#submit_msg {
    background: #FBB62D;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 95%;
}

form#submit_msg fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form#submit_msg fieldset:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

form#submit_msg legend {
    color: #b55100;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #a4a4a4;
}

form#submit_msg fieldset fieldset legend {
    color: #111111;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

form#submit_msg ol li {
    background: #b9cf6a;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-color: #e3ebc3;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
form#submit_msg ol ol li {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

form#submit_msg label {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 110px;
}
form#submit_msg fieldset fieldset label {
    background:none no-repeat left 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    width: auto;
}
form#submit_msg fieldset fieldset label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  If you need more information, I can provide you with login credentials to the site in order to see in realtime

Comment: Is the 'correct' really correct?  You really want all that contact info showing up to the left of the main page, instead of underneath the menus and to the right of the nav?  This looks really bizarre.

Comment: I'm using a 24" screen, so there's a lot of white.  Viewing it on a little bit smaller screen and it looks good (I think). But yes, the user logo and statistics I want in the orange sidebar

Comment: Reproduce the issue in a public URL and link us to it, nobody will take the time to implement a test-case on their own or contact you for credentials.

Comment: @Mario, makes sense.  www.beerbattle.net/skunk  login: stream@wargam.es   password: testaccount    To reproduce, click submit, then type 'bud' and click search.  Select any of the options, then click ok on the dialog box.  It will bring you to the page in question.  Thanks

Comment: Followed the instructions, did a lot of stuff, copied the links from the screenshots textually and absolutely NO WAY to get to the page with the issue. Please provide a static page with the exact HTML of it. I will take a look at it into 10 hours if there is no answer already.

Comment: Sorry, here you go.   https://beerbattle.net/skunk/html/correct.html    https://beerbattle.net/skunk/html/incorrect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your HTML. Your problem is that you have not closed some of your div tags. Fix those, and the page should be fine. 
[Validator report](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://beerbattle.net/skunk/html/incorrect.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Dom for correct page looks like this:

```
<div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="whitespace">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

While the incorrect is:

```
<div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="whitespace">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can see that the sidebar `<div>` is inside the content div.

Comment: I have closed off all div tags, but to no avail.  Still positioning in the wrong spot. =/